# Counting matching values with a function

Tags: python

I have the function below to check a list of dict values to determine whether a date is before today (overdue). The problem I'm having is that each time the function is called, `overdue` is being set to zero (because the function is being called again). Do I need to use a global variable?

```
from datetime import datetime

def overdue_tools(arg):
    overdue = 0
    today = datetime.now().date()
    try:
        due_date = datetime.strptime(arg, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
        if due_date < today:
            overdue += 1
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        print('Cannot convert {} to a date.'.format(arg))
    result = '<b>|</b> {} tools are overdue'.format(overdue)
    return result

s = ['01/01/2016', '02/02/2017', '04/05/2017', '05/06/2017']

for i in s:
    print overdue_tools(i)
```

This is the result:

```
me@computer:~/code$ python test.py
<b>|</b> 1 tools are overdue
<b>|</b> 1 tools are overdue
<b>|</b> 0 tools are overdue
<b>|</b> 0 tools are overdue
```

What I'm after is:

```
<b>|</b> 2 tools are overdue
```

I'm not sure of the best way to achieve this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have to modify the overdue function to handle the list and combine the result get from list and then print the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a predicate function `is_overdue` that does one thing (no formatting/message printing):

```
def is_overdue(arg):
    today = datetime.now().date()
    due_date = datetime.strptime(arg, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
    return due_date < today
```

Then filter the original list and count the remaining items:

```
print "overdue tools count: %d" % len([t for t in s if is_overdue(t)])
```

You can change formatting and exception handling to match your requirements.

Comment: You can also replace the list comprehension with `sum(is_overdue(t) for t in s)`

Comment: I rather be explicit and not rely on `True == 1` when explaining stuff here.

Answer (score 0):

You want to return a boolean from your function, and count each time it's `True`:

```
from datetime import datetime

def is_overdue(arg):
    overdue = False
    today = datetime.now().date()
    try:
        due_date = datetime.strptime(arg, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
        if due_date < today:
            overdue = True
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        print('Cannot convert {} to a date.'.format(arg))
    return overdue

s = ['01/01/2016', '02/02/2017', '04/05/2017', '05/06/2017']

number_overdue = 0
for i in s:
    if is_overdue(i):
        number_overdue += 1 

print '<b>|</b> {} tools are overdue'.format(number_overdue)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could pass the `overdue` variable to the function every time to save its value:

```
In [43]: from datetime import datetime
    ...: 
    ...: def overdue_tools(arg, overdue):
    ...:     today = datetime.now().date()
    ...:     try:
    ...:         due_date = datetime.strptime(arg, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
    ...:         if due_date < today:
    ...:             overdue += 1
    ...:     except (ValueError, TypeError):
    ...:         print('Cannot convert {} to a date.'.format(arg))
    ...:     return overdue
    ...: 
    ...: s = ['01/01/2016', '02/02/2017', '04/05/2017', '05/06/2017']
    ...: overdue = 0
    ...: for i in s:
    ...:     overdue = overdue_tools(i, overdue)
    ...:     print('<b>|</b> {} tools are overdue'.format(overdue))
    ...:     
<b>|</b> 1 tools are overdue
<b>|</b> 2 tools are overdue
<b>|</b> 2 tools are overdue
<b>|</b> 2 tools are overdue
```